# Using matlab FCM to cluster my own data

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to use fcm (fuzzy C-means clustering) matlab tool, but I don't know how to put my own data. I am trying to cluster nodes based on distance from the center. So my data are x and y coordinates. I am basically trying to compare it with k-means this is how I did the k-means:

```
X=[x_users,y_users];
nc=20;             
idx = kmeans(X,nc);
```

I need to know how to do the same thing with fcm, am sorry if my question is too naive.

Thanks,

Comment: `fcm(X,nc);` will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fcm(X,nc);
```

will do it. For example:

```
data = rand(100,2);
nc = 2;
[center,U,obj_fcn] = fcm(data,nc);
plot(data(:,1),data(:,2),'o');
maxU = max(U);
index1 = find(U(1,:)== maxU);
index2 = find(U(2,:)== maxU);
line(data(index1,1),data(index1,2),'linestyle','none',...
     'marker','*','color','g');
line(data(index2,1),data(index2,2),'linestyle','none',...
     'marker', '*','color','r');
```

[image]

Using `kmeans` the answer would be like the following plot:

```
idx = kmeans(data,nc);
data1 = data(idx==1,:);
data2 = data(idx==2,:);
figure;plot(data1(:,1),data1(:,2),'x');
hold on;plot(data2(:,1),data2(:,2),'or');
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot this is so helpful. How do I extract the centroids?

Comment: see centers in `[center,U,obj_fcn] = fcm(data,nc);` ?